# Use a different WHERE in no results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make this SQL statement simpler, and am looking for a way to change ONLY the `WHERE` clause if no results so I don't have to repeat the other part.

I've already tried with the `OR` and it's not what I need.

It searches first for a record that exactly matches the `ID` field.  If there is no result, it will then look for an `ID LIKE`.  If there is still no result, it will check the same input against the `Nombre` column.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM StockDetalles WHERE ID = '112')
BEGIN
SELECT        StockDetalles.ID, Negocios.NombreNegocio AS [Nombre Local], StockDetalles.Nombre, Stock.[Precio de Venta], Stock.Cantidad, 
                         Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Precio], Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Cantidad], StockDetalles.Proveedor, StockDetalles.[Precio de Compra], 
                         Stock.[Cantidad Reposicion], StockDetalles.CategoriaID, StockFotos.Foto
FROM            Stock INNER JOIN
                         StockDetalles ON Stock.ID = StockDetalles.ID INNER JOIN
                         Negocios ON Stock.IDNegocio = Negocios.IDNegocio INNER JOIN
                         StockFotos ON StockDetalles.ID = StockFotos.IDProducto
WHERE        (StockDetalles.ID = '112')
AND Stock.IDNegocio = 1
END
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM StockDetalles WHERE ID LIKE '%112%')
BEGIN
SELECT        StockDetalles.ID, Negocios.NombreNegocio AS [Nombre Local], StockDetalles.Nombre, Stock.[Precio de Venta], Stock.Cantidad, 
                         Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Precio], Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Cantidad], StockDetalles.Proveedor, StockDetalles.[Precio de Compra], 
                         Stock.[Cantidad Reposicion], StockDetalles.CategoriaID, StockFotos.Foto
FROM            Stock INNER JOIN
                         StockDetalles ON Stock.ID = StockDetalles.ID INNER JOIN
                         Negocios ON Stock.IDNegocio = Negocios.IDNegocio INNER JOIN
                         StockFotos ON StockDetalles.ID = StockFotos.IDProducto
WHERE        (StockDetalles.ID LIKE '%112%')
AND Stock.IDNegocio = 1
END
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM StockDetalles WHERE Nombre LIKE '%112%')
BEGIN
SELECT        StockDetalles.ID, Negocios.NombreNegocio AS [Nombre Local], StockDetalles.Nombre, Stock.[Precio de Venta], Stock.Cantidad, 
                         Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Precio], Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Cantidad], StockDetalles.Proveedor, StockDetalles.[Precio de Compra], 
                         Stock.[Cantidad Reposicion], StockDetalles.CategoriaID, StockFotos.Foto
FROM            Stock INNER JOIN
                         StockDetalles ON Stock.ID = StockDetalles.ID INNER JOIN
                         Negocios ON Stock.IDNegocio = Negocios.IDNegocio INNER JOIN
                         StockFotos ON StockDetalles.ID = StockFotos.IDProducto
WHERE        (StockDetalles.Nombre LIKE '%112%' )
AND Stock.IDNegocio = 1
END
```

Comment: Why cant you use OR? It looks like you don't care which record you actually get as long as you get one? Failing that you could create a Rank column and rank over your rules with a case statement

Comment: Becouse if i use OR between ID = '112' and ID LIKE '%112%' It will return the row with id 112 but also all the rows that may contain 33311255 or similar ID's wich i dont need if there is an exact record.

Comment: Your branched approach is probably a lot faster if you expect that most of the time the first query will find an exact match (and assuming that's an indexed column.)

Comment: If you keep the "branched" approach then also grab the ID(s) return by your existence check to avoid repeating costly `like '%x%'` searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OR` will work, you just have to get all the conditions right:

```
SELECT        StockDetalles.ID, Negocios.NombreNegocio AS [Nombre Local], StockDetalles.Nombre, Stock.[Precio de Venta], Stock.Cantidad, 
                         Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Precio], Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Cantidad], StockDetalles.Proveedor, StockDetalles.[Precio de Compra], 
                         Stock.[Cantidad Reposicion], StockDetalles.CategoriaID, StockFotos.Foto
FROM            Stock INNER JOIN
                         StockDetalles ON Stock.ID = StockDetalles.ID INNER JOIN
                         Negocios ON Stock.IDNegocio = Negocios.IDNegocio INNER JOIN
                         StockFotos ON StockDetalles.ID = StockFotos.IDProducto
WHERE 
    StockDetalles.ID = '112' OR -- the ID equals 112
    (StockDetalles.ID LIKE '%112%' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM StockDetalles WHERE ID = '112')) OR -- the ID is like 112, and no ID exists that equals 112
    (StockDetalles.Nombre  LIKE '%112%' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM StockDetalles WHERE ID LIKE '%112%')) -- the Nombre is like 112, and no ID exists that is like 112 (which would include any ID that exactly matched 112)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way with window functions:

```
;with cte1 as(select StockDetalles.ID,
                     Negocios.NombreNegocio AS [Nombre Local], 
                     StockDetalles.Nombre, 
                     Stock.[Precio de Venta], 
                     Stock.Cantidad, 
                     Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Precio],
                     Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Cantidad], 
                     StockDetalles.Proveedor, 
                     StockDetalles.[Precio de Compra], 
                     Stock.[Cantidad Reposicion],     
                     StockDetalles.CategoriaID, 
                     StockFotos.Foto,
                     row_number() over(order by case when id = '112' then 1
                                                     when id like '%112%' then 2
                                                     when nombre like '%112%' then 3 
                                                     else 4 end) rn1
              from Stock 
              join StockDetalles on Stock.ID = StockDetalles.ID 
              join Negocios on Stock.IDNegocio = Negocios.IDNegocio 
              join StockFotos on StockDetalles.ID = StockFotos.IDProducto
              where Stock.IDNegocio = 1),
cte2 as(select *, row_number() over(order by rn1) rn2 from cte1)
select * from cte2
where rn2 = 1 and rn1 <> 4
```

Comment: Your 3rd `when` is a little redundant, although you may prefer to be explicit. And wouldn't this query return a random row (from the implied `case...else...`) in the event there were no matches from the other three criteria, i.e., I think it still needs to filter rows in the `where` clause?

Comment: @shawnt00, don't think it is redundant, because all 3 statements can be true. For not matched rows you were correct and I have added that case to exclude any row in that case.

Comment: @shawnt00, correction: you were correct about redundance also. I have edited. Thanks.

Comment: It kind of works, but returns only 1 row when the << id like '%112%' then 2 >> condition fires up, AHiggins's solution returns as its supposed 5 rows

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Common Table Expression to make it a bit simpler a bit like this:

```
with stock_cte as
(SELECT  StockDetalles.ID ID, Negocios.NombreNegocio AS [Nombre Local], StockDetalles.Nombre Nombre,
Stock.[Precio de Venta] [Precio de Venta], Stock.Cantidad Cantidad, Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Precio] [Fecha Actualizacion de Precio],
Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Cantidad] [Fecha Actualizacion de Cantidad], StockDetalles.Proveedor Proveedor, StockDetalles.[Precio de Compra] [Precio de Compra],
Stock.[Cantidad Reposicion] [Cantidad Reposicion], StockDetalles.CategoriaID CategoriaID, StockFotos.Foto Foto

 FROM Stock 
 INNER JOIN StockDetalles ON Stock.ID = StockDetalles.ID 
 INNER JOIN Negocios ON Stock.IDNegocio = Negocios.IDNegocio 
 INNER JOIN StockFotos ON StockDetalles.ID = StockFotos.IDProducto

WHERE Stock.IDNegocio = 1)

Select *
from stock_cte sc
where exists (select 1 from StockDetalles where sc.ID = '112') OR
      (not exists (select 1 from StockDetalles where sc.ID = '112') and
       exists(SELECT 1 FROM StockDetalles WHERE sc.ID LIKE '%112%')) OR
      (not exists (select 1 from StockDetalles where sc.ID = '112') and 
       not exists(SELECT 1 FROM StockDetalles WHERE sc.ID LIKE '%112%') and 
       sc.Nombre LIKE '%112%')
```

Comment: Returns all the rows that contain 112 on their ID
`code3789111200895
6931471123988
7790011001129
7790002001121
6934392901123
7702111261952
7451121145645
2513931111120
7792451120040
6991251127711
2501125405650
7792216675112
7792281041126`code

Comment: Is that not what your query does? I'm confused as to what you want. This should return all rows with ID = 112 or if that doesn't exist all rows with ID like 112 and if that doesn't exist all rows with Nombre like 112. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Correct. Cristian thats what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

As I've said above try adding a order by case

```
select TOP 1 * 
From
(
SELECT '123' as a, '122345' as b UNION
Select '#123#', '' union
select 'abc', '122'
)t 

order by CASE WHEN a like '123' THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN a LIKE '%123%' THEN 2 ELSE CASE WHEN b like '%122%' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END END END
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this, but i hav eno idea how tomake it work

```
SELECT  StockDetalles.ID ID, Negocios.NombreNegocio AS [Nombre Local], StockDetalles.Nombre Nombre,
Stock.[Precio de Venta] [Precio de Venta], Stock.Cantidad Cantidad, Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Precio] [Fecha Actualizacion de Precio],
Stock.[Fecha Actualizacion de Cantidad] [Fecha Actualizacion de Cantidad], StockDetalles.Proveedor Proveedor, StockDetalles.[Precio de Compra] [Precio de Compra],
Stock.[Cantidad Reposicion] [Cantidad Reposicion], StockDetalles.CategoriaID CategoriaID, StockFotos.Foto Foto

 FROM Stock 
 INNER JOIN StockDetalles ON Stock.ID = StockDetalles.ID 
 INNER JOIN Negocios ON Stock.IDNegocio = Negocios.IDNegocio 
 INNER JOIN StockFotos ON StockDetalles.ID = StockFotos.IDProducto

WHERE Stock.IDNegocio = 1 AND 
(
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT StockDetalles.ID FROM StockDetalles WHERE StockDetalles.ID = '112')
    THEN StockDetalles.ID = '112'
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT StockDetalles.ID FROM StockDetalles WHERE StockDetalles.ID LIKE '%112%')
    THEN StockDetalles.ID LIKE '%112%'
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT StockDetalles.ID FROM StockDetalles WHERE StockDetalles.Nombre LIKE '%112%')
    THEN StockDetalles.Nombre LIKE '%112%'
END
)
```